# How to pass vector of vectors into open CL

Tags: c++, opencl

I would like to know if it is possible to send a data structure like this into Open CL

```
  std::vector<std::vector<unsigned> > v;
```

The catch is that I do not know the size of either vectors until run time also each inner vector is of varying size.

Is this even possible, if so how would I do it in both the kernel and host.

Thanks

Comment: What's the signature of the function you are trying to call? Likely you need to turn your `vector` into an array of sorts

Answer (score 0):

Get total size of

```
std::vector<std::vector<unsigned> > v;
```

multiply it with 2. Allocate that much memory for an array. Use it(copy from vectors to it). Next time you get these vectors, check total size again. If size changes, check if greater than the length of last array allocated. If yes, re-allocate with x2 multiplied length. If-no, re-use. Repeat. If new vector size is less than quarter of allocated array length for  the last 5 iterations, allocate an array with half length. Don't forget freeing old arrays. Maybe you can build a LRU-policy cache out of these arrays(5-10 of them maybe?). Of course copying from vector to array takes time but it shouldn't take longer than copying each sub vectors one by one to device memory